# How many ways can 30 games be played?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, binomial-distribution

In a typical CSGO game, 2 teams play each other for a best out of 30 (First team to 16 wins if a team reaches 16 wins). My question is what is the probability a CSGO game goes 30 games and wanted to see if my solution was correct.

I will consider $p=\text{probability team A wins}$, $q=\text{probability team B wins}$

The only way to reach 30 games is either a tie (15-15) or if the match comes to (14-15) on the 29th round and then turns to (14-16). Likewise the match could also be (15-14) on the 29th round and become (16-14)

So I was thinking for the 15-15 situation it would be 30C15$*p^{15}q^{15}$

For the 15-14 situation I figured 29C15$*p^{15}q^{14}*p$

For the 14-15 situation I figured 29C15$*p^{14}q^{15}*q$

I then took these 3 probabilities and added them for roughly a 29% chance of happening (this is if we assume $p=q=.5$)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid splitting it in three cases and doing it just 2. I mean if we know that there hasn't been a winner after 29 games, the result in the last one doesn't matter too much. Hence you need to only find when the results are $15-14$ or $14-15$ after 29 rounds.

Comment: Do you mean to disregard the 15-15 round separately and look at the 29: 15-14, 14-15 rounds? (Also, I think I need both 14-15,15-14 since I want to count both) My interpretation was: 29C15*$p^{15}q^{14}$(p+q)+29C14*$p^{14}q^{15}$(p+q)?

Comment: You can disregard it because you only need to check the first 29 games to see whether the 30th will be played. We don't care what happens there. Your result is correct, after all $p+q = 1$, right?

Comment: ok thanks. And yes, I was adding in the p+q as if the 30th game was played (but p+q=1 which simplifies)